# Echo content from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created two tables:

Table 1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `l_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `treatment_log` (
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Table 2** references **Table 1** through the Forging Key "treatment_fk" -> "id". 
**I would like to echo a specific customer in Table 1 and all of their corresponding rows in Table 2**.

How do I implement it in PHP?

Mysql connection details are as follows:

```
('DB_HOST', "localhost");
('DB_USER', "root");
('DB_PASSWORD', "");
('DB_NAME', "test");
```

My code so far allows me to display the content of TABLE 1 and enables the user to edit his information. The only part that is missing is the display of the content in TABLE 2 in a bootstrap table.

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default "string" type field. There's no reason to limit names to thirty characters, as that may prove to be inadequate. Also try and standarize things like country codes using [ISO-3166 Alpha 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) instead of free-form text.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT c.*, t.* FROM customers c, treatment_log t INNER JOIN treatment_log ON c.id = t.treatment_fk WHERE c.id = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Hey im a little lost, could you write this entirely as a PHP. It doesn't seem to work when I write it. Including variables echo etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a MySQL Join.

Documentation on joins: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html
Helpful article: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Image to help out to visually understand the join concept
[image]

Good luck!